# Explaining conservation of angular momentum with a disconnect

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotation

A probe is rotating in space and an instrument comes loose and disconnects. I need to explain why the angular velocity $\omega$ of the probe does not change.

This equation describes how the angular momentums can be considered separately ($I$ denotes moment of inertia).

$$ L = (I_{probe} + I_{instrument}) \omega $$

But, once the instrument disconnects it is no longer rotating so it's $L_{instrument}$ value is nonexistent. But this contradicts what I need to explain, as this would imply that $L_{probe}$ increases to keep $L_{total}$ constant. What am I explaining wrong here?

Comment: $L$ is calculated about a particular axis.  Are you changing that axis when calculating $L_{instrument}$ after it disconnects?

Comment: No, but when the instrument disconnects it doesn't have an axis or radius so I'm not sure what to do there.

Comment: You keep the same axis.  Even objects moving in a straight line can have angular momentum.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148319/has-a-body-angular-momentum-and-torque-only-in-a-circular-path

Comment: Could you clarify on that? Is r just changing then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you mention that when the instrument disconnects, it is no longer rotating.  Why would that be?

However, the bigger issue is that if you want to conserve angular momentum, you have to measure it in the same way each time.  For angular momentum, that means you have to retain the same axis each time.

The instrument may no longer be rotating around the original axis, but it does retain the angular momentum around that axis.

$$L = rvm \sin(\theta)$$

When it was attached to the probe, the distance from the axis ($r$) was a constant.  After it disconnects, $r$ increases, but $r\sin(\theta)$ stays a constant.

[image]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Specific_angular_momentum.svg

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  If I spin a baseball on a string, then let go of the string, the baseball does not continue to revolve around me - it travels in a straight line, tangent to the original orbit.

Comment: I don't say anywhere here that it would continue to revolve around the probe.  It does move in a straight line, but it still has angular momentum.

Comment: I think that the only revolving @Dylanthepiguy is asking about is around the probe.  I don't think he's talking about the probe/instrument system revolving around a planet or anything like that.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Nothing here has anything to do with revolving around a planet.  Perhaps I need to clarify something in the answer?

Comment: Nevermind - I was confused.